Browser extension breaking event listener
Current setup is a PHP form which customers put in an iframe with a submit button. Chrome browser extensions like TopCashBack are sending message events like:
{message: 'ACK_FRAME', targetId: 'bef025c4-852a-4b55-2ced-fcf777c43091'}

The fields sent come into this function:
function postFields(msg){
    var receiver = document.getElementById('iframe-content').contentWindow;
    receiver.postMessage(msg, 'https://my.websitecom');
}

Which this eventlistener is picking up.
        if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage);
        }

Thinking that I need to be checking the origin of the browser, or somehow block extension interactions with this page?

What's SecureMessage? The event for postMessage() calls is just message. Also, window always has addEventListener, that's part of the spec. globalThis might not (e.g. in Node rather than the browser) but you're not using that.

Sorry mistake* recently chrome extensions have started pushing events using the message object.

That change radically changes things, so: did you only change the word in your post, or does your code actually use message? On that note, it would be useful for you to form a [mcve] (to verify you can even form one) and then put that in your post.

I resolved the issue by checking the event data and ensuring that it contains the specific properties I need before proceeding with further processing.
if (!event.data || !event.data.myThingamabob) {
    console.log("Certain browser extensions may be unsupported or causing issues. Please disable extensions and try again.");
    return;
}

